# Can boost::python pass ownership of an object to a python callback function?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am currently passing a C++ pointer to a python callback function with the `boost::python::call` function. This works fine, but if I don't subsequently delete the pointer in the C++ code, I introduce a memory leak.

I would like to pass the pointer to the callback and have python's garbage collector handle the lifetime of the object. Right now, if I want to save the object passed to the callback, I have to do a deep copy.

I have seen [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/PointersAndSmartPointers) that this sort of thing is possible with return values of wrapped C++ function with `return_value_policy<manage_new_object>`. Is it possible to do something similar with the arguments to `boost::python::call`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way [`manage_new_object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/manage_new_object.html) works is by being a metafunction class that converts an argument into a converted result that the caller must take responsibility for. With the normal call policies, it's used under the hood. We just have to use that metafunction class explicitly ourselves:

```
struct Foo {
    X* x = ...;

    void give_up_x(py::object callback) {
        py::manage_new_object::apply<X*>::type wrapper;
        callback(py::handle<>{wrapper(x)});
    }
};
```

You need `py::handle<>` since wrapper gives you back a `PyObject*` instead of a `py::object`. If you want to be more direct, you can skip some of the intermediate type instantiations and just use:

```
void give_up_x(py::object callback) {
    callback(py::handle<>{py::detail::make_owning_holder::execute(x)});
}
```

---

I came upon the above through guess-and-check. It looks like it works at least?